# Visual Studio Community 2013で C# を使ったチーム開発で DLL への Reference 設定も共有したい

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Visual Studio Community 2013 で C#を使って開発をしようとしています。チームで共同作業です。
プロジェクトを SVN にコミットして複数人で共同開発を行います。

利用したい外部 DLL がいくつかあり、これを一番簡単に間違いなく管理したいのですが、やり方がわかりません。

なお、現在は、プロジェクトディレクトリの下に lib というディレクトリを作って、そこに DLL を放り込み、 Solution Explorer で References に追加しています。

しかしこの方法だと、他のメンバーが初めてプロジェクトを開く時に同様の手順で References を追加する必要があり、不便ですしミスを招きそうです。

Solution の DLL の管理はどのように行うのがベストでしょうか？  
他に良い方法があれば教えて下さい。

Comment: 共有サーバー上にnugetのリポジトリを作成し、nugetパッケージとしてdllを共有しては、どうでしょう？

Comment: 自己解決した場合には自身で回答を記載し、回答の承認をよろしくお願いします。そうすると本質問が解決済みであることが他の方にもわかりやすくなりますので。

Comment: 回答記載しました。回答の承認とはどうすればよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決しました。

絶対パス(ではないけど一度ルートまで戻るような相対パス)で書かれていました。修正したところ、無事共有する‌​ことが出来ました。

Answer (score 1):

プロジェクトファイルでは相対パスで管理されています。「他のメンバーが初めてプロジェクトを開く時」には既に登録済みです。
プロジェクトを作成する時にのみ登録が必要ですが、プロジェクト作成の頻度は低くミスを招くことはあまりないと思いますが、どうでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。

私もそう思ったのですが、実際に別のPCで開いて見たところdllがリンク切れを起こしReferencesの当該dllのプロパティでPathの部分は空となっていました。

通常は、この様なことは発生しないのでしょうか？

Comment: それを尋ねるべきかと…。少なくとも私のところでは管理できていてsvn作業コピーの場所に依存していません。
もしかするとプロジェクト作成時に絶対パスとなっているかもしれませんが、プロジェクトファイルはXMLですので相対パスに書き換え可能です。

Comment: はい。申し訳ないです。他にmavenのようなツールがあってSolutionとかをいじらない可能性もあるかと思いまして、質問内容を広めにしてしまいました。

通常は相対パスで管理可能ということですね。
プロジェクトファイルを開いて確認したところ相対パスになっているようです。

    <Reference Include="PdfSharp">
      <HintPath>lib\PdfSharp.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>

Solutionを開いた際の動きなど、もう一度確認してみます。

Comment: 解決しました。

申し訳ないです。もう一度.csprojを確認したところ、絶対パス(ではないけど一度ルートまで戻るような相対パス)で書かれていました。修正したところ、無事共有することが出来ました。ありがとうございます。